# How to temporarily leave fakeroot environment

Tags: shell-script, scripting, permissions, chmod, fakeroot

To run some tests, I want to revoke write permissions for a folder. This is a minimal example:

```
$ mkdir test
$ chmod a-w test
$ touch test/test || printf '%s\n' "write permissions successfully revoked"
touch: cannot touch 'test/test': Permission denied
write permissions successfully revoked
```

However, if I run it with fakeroot, this doesn't work:

```
$ fakeroot sh  
# mkdir test
# chmod a-w test
# touch test/test || printf '%s\n' "write permissions successfully revoked"
# ls test
test
```

For an explanation **why** this doesn't work, see this question, for example: [Issue with changing permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/538045/issue-with-changing-permissions/538051)

However, my question is: how can I get around this? Can I temporarily disable fakeroot for the `chmod` command? Or can I make fakeroot permission changes permanent anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fakeroot` is using a `LD_PRELOAD` hack to load a small shared library which overrides some library functions like `chmod(2)`, `chown(2)`, etc. See the [`ld.so(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) manpage for details (there are also a lot of examples on this site).

Just run a command with the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable unset or set to an empty string, and that library will not be loaded:

```
$ fakeroot sh
$ chown root:root fo.c
$ LD_PRELOAD= chown root:root fo.c
chown: changing ownership of 'fo.c': Operation not permitted
```